# How to get last element in a ForeignKey relation?

Tags: django

To describe my problem I will use basic models :

```
class Chatroom(Model):
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=3000)

class Message(Model):
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=3000)
    room = models.ForeignKey(
        Chatroom,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='messages'
    )
```

I want to display every last message sent to a room ordered by the date of creation. In practice, the user connects to the page and she/he can see the messages ordered by date, but only the last message of each room.

Example : in the database we have:

```
rooms = [RoomA, RoomB]

messages = [
{
  text: 'firstA',
  date_created: 01/05/21,
  room: RoomA
},
{
  text: 'secondA',
  date_created: 03/05/21,
  room: RoomA
},
{
  text: 'firstB',
  date_created: 02/05/21,
  room: RoomB
},
{
  text: 'secondB',
  date_created: 06/05/21,
  room: RoomB
},
]
```

As a result of my queryset, I want to get last messages of each room, meaning messages [secondB, secondA].

Currently I am doing the following :

```
        messages_uids = Message.objects \
            .order_by('room_id') \
            .distinct('room_id') \
            .values_list('pk', flat=True)

        queryset = Message.objects \
            .filter(pk__in=messages_uids) \
            .order_by('-date_created')

        return queryset
```

I have only one message per room (good point), messages are ordered by date_created (good point), but I do not have the last message of each room. With the previous set of example, I get [secondA, firstB]. I understand that it is due to `order_by('room_id')` and `distinct('room_id'` : the queryset will select only one message by room, but not necessarily the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
messages_uids = Message.objects \
    .order_by('room_id', '-date_created') \
    .distinct('room_id') \
    .values_list('pk', flat=True)
```

But note that you're guaranteed to get the last element only if you use PostgreSQL. From Django docs:

> On PostgreSQL only, you can pass positional arguments (*fields) in
> order to specify the names of fields to which the DISTINCT should
> apply. This translates to a SELECT DISTINCT ON SQL query. Here’s the
> difference. For a normal distinct() call, the database compares each
> field in each row when determining which rows are distinct. For a
> distinct() call with specified field names, the database will only
> compare the specified field names.

Comment: That is working thanks ! Simply by adding '-date_created'. I was busy trying with SubQuery https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions ;) That worked too but it was more complicated